# When does $A$ and $|A|$ have same set of eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix and $|A|$ denotes the entry-wise modulus of $A$. Now what should be the structure of $A$ such that $A$ and $|A|$ will always have the same set of eigenvalues?

Comment: Spectral theorem

Comment: Yes, surely if $A$ and $|A|$ are similar, then they possess the same set of eigenvalues. But I am interested know, what should be the structure of these matrices or a class of matrices which follow the same condition.